# How to wait for just the first task to complete

Tags: julia

If there are a set of concurrent tasks scheduled, how to wait for the first task to complete?.

Does exists something like `wait([t1, t2], return_when=:FIRST_COMPLETED)`?

```
function task1()
    rt = rand()
    @info "task1 time: $rt"
    sleep(rt)
    @info "task 1 done"
end

function task2()
    rt = rand()
    @info "task2 time: $rt"
    sleep(rt)
    @info "task 2 done"
end

t1 = @async task1()
t2 = @async task2()

# wait for just the first completed task
# ???
```

Comment: You could have both write to a channel and then blockingly read from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this would work:

```
julia> function waitfirst(ts)
           c = Channel{Int}()
           for (i, t) in enumerate(ts)
               @async begin
                   wait(t)
                   put!(c, i)
               end
           end
           r = take!(c)
           @info "Task $r won"
       end
waitfirst (generic function with 1 method)

julia> waitfirst([@async(task1()), @async(task2())])
[ Info: task1 time: 0.6723665203367726
[ Info: task2 time: 0.4815093245244271
[ Info: task 2 done
[ Info: Task 2 won

julia> [ Info: task 1 done
julia> 

julia> waitfirst([@async(task1()), @async(task2())])
[ Info: task1 time: 0.3452659680724035
[ Info: task2 time: 0.8576370382519976
[ Info: task 1 done
[ Info: Task 1 won

julia> [ Info: task 2 done
julia>
```

You have to make sure the inputs are scheduled first, though, otherwise it deadlocks.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to channel, you can also use `Condition`s like this:

```
c = Condition()
t1 = @async (task1(); notify(c))
t2 = @async (task2(); notify(c))
wait(c)
@info "wake"
```

Note this only schedule the main task, not directly switch to it. i.e. it is possible that when `t1` finished, the main task is waken, but `t2` get scheduled first and do some computation heavy work (blocking) before the main task actually continue. You can take a look at `yield` if you want to make sure the main task runs first.

Comment: I also like this approach, but when encapsulating into a `wait_for(task_list)` function it does not work.
When the first task complete `wait_for` returns and `c` Condition variable goes out of scope:
when the next task completes you get an`UndefVarError: c not defined` exception.

Comment: It's strange. It is referenced in the implicit closure defined by `@async` and should not be garbage collected.

Comment: You are right! There is no reason for an `UndefVarError`, it was my fault code.